# The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. Try correcting the name. - Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

The `child` in this code is bringing up the error: `The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'child'.`
The Code:

```
child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          height: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Center(...
```

What I've tried:
I've tried to search this error on Stack Overflow but everyone says that after: `flutter clean cache`, restart IDE, restart app, rerun, hot reload, reboot it should work. But this is not the case. So I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You've forgot to add Decoration end `)`  ..  `  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          **),**
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Center(...
```

You forgot to add

> ),

before

> child: Column(...

Please share your full code if this doesn't work.